# Wordpress form field not expanded

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, plugins, shortcode

Currently there’s a problem with the form display on our wordpress site. Was looking at it and thought it might have been a plugin conflict. Tried deactivating some but the problem still persists.

This is how the form looks like on this site 1. Notice that the form fields is much smaller in width and when clicked on, it has a textbox shown which may be the reason why the width is restricted.

[form with problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehcBw.jpg)

This is how the form looks like on site 2 (intended):

[form that looks as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Q9L.jpg)

We’re using cornerstone and a custom plugin for the wordpress shortcode that represents the form - so when i paste the shortcode in a textbox on cornerstone the form shows up instead.

The plugin code has been checked to be the same for both sites, so it should not be the source of the problem. Also, the wordpress form code for the form works on our other wordpress sites, so that might not be the problem too. So it probably narrows down to wordpress.

The problems are summarised:

1. Form textbox width differences between same forms on different sites
2. Form showing a textbox when typed in but the form in the other site
   doesn't
3. Colour of "submit" button not fully grey when mouse is not hovered
   on it -> with some red covering it

The thing is, we don't want the changes to the forms to only affect one page, but want it across the problem site.

Can anyone help to diagnose the problem above? Many thanks!

Comment: I believe the problem is with your CSS. Please changes the CSS of your text box using !important keyword. Try "width:100% !important;" for your textbox.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Do i edit the css in the themes? If so, which file do i edit? Because i am just pasting the shortcode, i dont know if i can do that per form. Also, if i edit the css for one page's form, i would have to do that for all pages on the site.

Comment: You can easily find out which CSS file by using Inspect Element of Chrome. Apply CSS to that specific class (if available) and it will work throughout your website. You could also define CSS in style.css. Go to Apperence->Editor->Style.css. If you are still not able to fix problem, kindly share your page URL!!

Comment: Thank you! I found that he edited under additional css of wordpress theme. :) But as for how to remove the textbox when typing a name on the form i still haven't got that figured out.